# No suitable method to override Update(GameTime gameTime)

Tags: c#-4.0, xna-4.0

I get the error as said above, which prevents me from testing to see whether my camera is working. The code is:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    KeyboardState keyBoardState = Keyboard.GetState();

    //Rotate Cube along its Up Vector
    if (keyBoardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.X))
    {
        cubeWorld = Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(Vector3.Up, .02f) * cubeWorld;
    }
    if (keyBoardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Z))
    {
        cubeWorld = Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(Vector3.Up, -.02f) * cubeWorld;
    }

    //Move Cube Forward, Back, Left, and Right
    if (keyBoardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
    {
        cubeWorld *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(cubeWorld.Forward);
    }
    if (keyBoardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
    {
        cubeWorld *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(cubeWorld.Backward);
    }
    if (keyBoardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
    {
        cubeWorld *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(-cubeWorld.Right);
    }
    if (keyBoardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
    {
        cubeWorld *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(cubeWorld.Right);
    }
}
```

The line causing an error is:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
```

Comment: Are you sure your base class has the method you're trying to override?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not inheriting from GameComponent, you have two options:

1. Inherite your class from GameComponent:

   ```
   public class YourCameraClass : GameComponent { .... }
   ```
2. Remove the 'override' keyword in your update method declaration:

   ```
   public void Update(Gametime gametime) {....}
   ```

Comment: I can't delete the protected, it throws an exception.

Comment: Could this possibly have something to do with it being a GraphicsDeviceControl and not a Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game?